# bibTeX + Kile + mageia (KDE) = error?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, kile

I can't get the bibliography printed in the final pdf after I compile the *main.tex* file with pdfLaTeX in Kile. I'm using Mageia OS with a KDE desktop environment. This is the error I get when I try to compile the main.tex with bibtex:

`[BibTeX]main.aux => main.bbl (bibtex)`

`[BibTeX]finished with exit code 2`

I pressed the bibtex button on *mybibliography.bib*: that didn't work. Next, I compiled (I tried) *main.tex* with pdfLaTeX and got 0 errors, and a number of warnings:

`LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sharbati:2009' on page 3 undefined on input line 2.`

`LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 51.`

`LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`

`Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)main(biblatex)and rerun LaTeX afterwards.`

Comment: BibTeX is used on the `.aux` file: either `bibtex main` or `bibtex main.aux`.  Alternatively, Biber uses a `.bcf` file: either `biber main` or `biber main.bcf`.  If you are using `biblatex`, you are encouraged to use Biber (add `backend=biber` to the options of `biblatex` just to be clear); but you can use BibTeX if you prefer (`backend=bibtex`).  It sounds like you are not specifying the backend and `biblatex` defaults to `biber`, but are trying nevertheless to use `bibtex`.  You need to check your Kile settings.  If that's not the problem, you need to post a minimal example (search for MWE).

Answer (score 2):

Your error message indicates that you are using `biblatex`, which supports many different backends: `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, `bibtexu`, `biber`.  It now defaults to `biber`, since it was designed specifically for `biblatex` and provides much more functionality than any `bibtex`-based backends.  If you want to use a different backend, say `bibtex`, you need to inform `biblatex` by adding the appropriate option (among any others you also wish to use):

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

There are also implications for what files need to be processed based on the backend.  With `bibtex`, you use the `.aux` file to create the bibliography; the command sequence is:

```
latex  myfile.tex
bibtex myfile.aux
latex  myfile.tex
latex  myfile.tex
```

(Note that the file extension does not need to be said explicitly, but these are the specific files that `latex` and `bibtex` are using.)

With `biber` it is slightly different:

```
latex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
latex myfile.tex
```

(Note again that the extensions are unnecessary.  Also, other packages might need a third `latex` run, but `biber` doesn't unless you do something like writing a `\cite` command in an entry in your `.bib` file. It also doesn't hurt to remind yourself that you are using `biber` by specifying `backend=biber` in your loading of `biblatex`.)

Now, in order to get `Kile` to know you are using `biber` instead of `bibtex`, you probably need to change some of the default settings.  I don't use `Kile` and no longer have it installed, but according to the [documentation](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/build.html#id329006), you can access these settings in '`Settings` -> `Configure Kile`... -> `Tools+Build` in the `General` tab in the LaTeX and PDFLaTeX tools`